# Magento 1.9 newsletter spam

Tags: magento-1.9, spam

How to prevent bots creating fake subscibers to newsletter list ?
They are making direct GET / POST requests to `/customer/account/create/` and `/newsletter/subscriber/new/`

```
"GET /customer/account/create/ HTTP/1.1" 200 82432 "-" "-"
"POST /newsletter/subscriber/new/ HTTP/1.1" 302 3874 "-" "-"
```

If i try to subscribe with curl it does not work, but somehow bots can still create subscribers

`curl 'https://shop.com/newsletter/subscriber/new/'  --data 'email=example@example.com'`

Login page has working recaptcha!

Comment: You may use the captcha!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the newsletter subscription confirmation feature in Magento. Enable this from:

```
admin-login >> System >> Configuration >> Customer >> Newsletter >> select Yes from Need to confirm drop-down option.
```

I hope this will help you.